# How can I configure Jenkins to run declarative Jenkinsfiles on GitHub Pull Request (PR) Close or Merge?

Tags: github, jenkins, github-webhook

In a recent build of Jenkins (i.e., 2021-10-01 timeframe), how can I react to a GitHub pull request (PR) Close (or Merge) using declarative Jenkinsfiles and ONLY these "basic" Jenkins plugins?

1. [GitHub plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/)
2. [GitHub branch source plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source/)

It seems that I should avoid [GitHub Pull Request Builder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/) since [it can't react to PR close or merge](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/209).

Currently, everything works fine using a "GitHub organization" type project, when opening the PR and creating new commits on it (i.e., I see `"continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge"`), but when I click `Close pull Request` in GitHub, the Jenkins Build History doesn't react. I'm not sure why since, the "GitHub branch source plugin" states:

> While the build triggers are often enough, you can set up webhooks to
> automatically trigger builds when changes are pushed to your GitHub
> repositories.